# 32-bit Java doesn't work on 32-bit Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, java

Please understand that this is not a duplicate of the other questions that I have seen so far.

So basically, I installed Java on my system, and when I go to the Java website to let it detect the version, Chrome tells me that the Java plugin is required, and I have to install it. The problem is, I already have Java! Apparently, Chrome didn't see it.

Another question tells users to get the Java 32-bit version (I have Windows 7 64-bit), because Chrome is a 32-bit application. I reinstalled that version instead, but that didn't work either. I went on chrome://plugins/, and Java wasn't on the list. I have Kaspersky PURE 3.0 Total Security, and another place told users to disable that, so I did. That still didn't work.

The error was on the yellow bar saying "Java(TM) is required to display some elements on this page"; beside it was the "Install Plug-in..." button, with the "Problems Installing?" link on the right.

I installed Java 7u45 from Oracle's website. Please help.

Comment: What version of Chrome do you have installed?  You installed the following file?  http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/AutoDL?BundleId=81819  The next step will be to use a program called Java Ra to wipe all traces of java from your computer http://singularlabs.com/software/javara/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow link - [Chrome and Java](http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml)

64-Bit Chrome is a **MUST** for 64 bit Java on Windows. Exact words in above link is-
Starting with Chrome version 37, Chrome is available in 64-bit format on Windows. When running 64-bit Chrome, the user **must** also have 64-bit Java installed.

To check your Chrome-bitness follow below instruction:

In the Chrome address bar enter:
chrome://help/
Check the version information.
If it is a 64-bit Chrome version, it will have (64-bit) after the version number, otherwise it is a 32-bit version of Chrome.

All you need to install is 64-bit chrome and it will start recognizing Java.
Currently 64-bit chrome is available only in its beta version and I am running it happily.

I believe this will end your problems(at least above one :P ).

Comment: I have chrome and java both x64 and both fully installed and I was using them. But, now (maybe because of Win update (I use Win 7 x64)) it says that "a plug-in is required ...". As many as I install the link the error re-appear! Do you have any idea?

Comment: Try these links - https://java.com/en/download/help/enable_browser.xml , https://java.com/en/download/help/enable_panel.xml and https://www.java.com/en/download/help/browser_activate_plugin.xml

Answer (score 0):

You need Java 32 bit for Chrome, I had the same problem. Java in IE worked, but in Chrome and Firefox not. In **chrome** `chrome://plugins/` You have to see:

> Java(TM) (2 files) - Version: 10.55.2.14
>
> NPRuntime Script Plug-in Library for Java(TM) Deploy
>
> Name:  Java Deployment Toolkit 7.0.550.14
>
> Description:   NPRuntime Script Plug-in Library for Java(TM) Deploy
>
> Version:   10.55.2.14
>
> Location:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\dtplugin\npDeployJava1.dll
>
> Type:  NPAPI
>        Disable
>    MIME types:
>
> MIME type    Description File extensions
>
> application/java-deployment-toolkit
>
> Name:  Java(TM) Platform SE 7 U55
>
> Description:   Next Generation Java Plug-in 10.55.2 for Mozilla browsers
>
> Version:   10.55.2.14
>
> Location:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\plugin2\npjp2.dll
>
> Type:  NPAPI
>        Disable

If there is missing Platform SE 7 U55
problem is in Registry

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MozillaPlugins\@java.com/DTPlugin,version=10.55.2`

and

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MozillaPlugins\@java.com/JavaPlugin,version=10.55.2`

Check the path for both key if it is correct, it should by

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\dtplugin\npDeployJava1.dll`

and

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\plugin2\npjp2.dll`

Just correct path and restart Chrome